# How to initialize firebase admin using modular Firebase v9?

Tags: node.js, firebase-admin, es6-modules

I'm using firebase admin to interact with `Firestore` and `auth` from a custom backend (next.js api routes).

Firebase recently [announced](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) they're going with modular tree-shaking packages.

How can I refactor below code to utilize tree-shaking firebase module?

```
import * as firebaseAdmin from "firebase-admin";

if (!firebaseAdmin.apps.length) {
  const adminCredentials = {
    credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert({
      projectId: env.fbProjIdPublic,
      clientEmail: env.fbClientEmail,
      privateKey: JSON.parse(env.fbPvtKey),
    }),
    databaseURL: env.fbDbUrlPublic,
  };

  firebaseAdmin.initializeApp(adminCredentials);
}

export default firebaseAdmin;
```

So far I couldn't find replacement for `firebaseAdmin.credential.cert`.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation you linked is for the Web/JavaScript SDK, not for the Node.js Admin SDKs.

A modular Admin SDK for Node.js is under development, but not generally available yet. You can find the latest information and how to join the alpha program [here](https://modular-admin.web.app/).

You can also track its progress on the Github repo, like on this recent [feature request](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1426), and this [request for feedback](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1332) from the engineers working on it.

Comment: is it advisable to use modular version as v10 is now released https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/releases/tag/v10.0.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried and this works.

Env variables not being strings was my problem on local

```
import { initializeApp, App, AppOptions, getApps, getApp, cert } from "firebase-admin/app";


const clientEmail = process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL;
const privateKey = process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY;
const projectId = process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID;

const firebaseAdminConfig: AppOptions = {
  credential: cert({
    clientEmail,
    privateKey,
    projectId,
  }),
};
```